# Escaping/sanitizing data retrieved from the database

Tags: sql, security, database-security

Let's say I have a web application that gets input from the user and saves it in a database.  Let's further assume that there are no security vulnerabilities -- it correctly escapes user input, uses bind parameters, whatever.

Must data retrieved from the database be treated with suspicion (i.e. as potentially tainted/malicious)?

---

Example (not sure of the result because I'm afraid to try it).  This is the database:

```
create table mytable (id int primary key, name varchar(50));

create table othertable (name varchar(50), xyz int, 
    ... `name` is an fk ...);

insert into mytable (id, name) values(1, '"abc"; drop table mytable;');

insert into othertable (name, xyz) values('"abc"; drop table mytable;', 45475);
```

Then I run this pseudo-code (maybe from PHP, for example):

```
# run query 'select * from mytable where id = 1';

# put the `name` in $name

# run query 'select * from othertable where name = $name'
# $name is not escaped, no other precautions taken
```

Answer (score 1):

You MUST escape again.  All escaping does is say 'SQL, this isn't a command oriented ', it's a part of the data'.  So if you escape " 'one' ", SQL will store " \'one\' ", and output... " 'one' ".  Which means that you have to escape all over again.

Better yet, instead of using the regular mysql_ functions, use prepared statements from either mysqli_ or PDO.  I'm moving my own programming approaches over because they obviate the need for escaping.  (The basic idea is that instead of sending a query string which has to be parsed with the data 'in place', you send over a query string with placeholders, and then tell SQL 'remember that query I gave you earlier?  Use values X, Y, and Z in it.  As a result, the values never have a chance to corrupt the processing of the actual query)

Answer (score 0):

The vulnerability happens at the point where you substitute the `$name`.  Always escape before substituting.